# Instead of "sum-free" sets, consider sets where $S\subset S+S$. This is trivially satisfied when $0 \in S$. Is there a subset of $S$ with sum $0$?

Tags: combinatorics, sumset

As an example, here is a set $S$ with $S\subset S+S$ and $|S|=8$ and having subsets of four elements whose sum is zero, but no smaller subsets have this property: $S=\{-14,-13,-11,-7,1,2,4,8\}$. This can be easily generalized to sets having $2n$ elements, containing the powers of two, up to $2^n$ and suitable negative elements, allowing subsets of $n$ elements with sum zero, but no smaller subsets have this property.
In general, it is easy to find a sequence (or multi-set) of size at most $|S|/2$ having sum zero. So the question is if we could actually find a subset of $S$ with zero sum.

Comment: Do you assume that $S$ is finite?

Comment: So you have a set $S$ that has the title property $S \subset S+S$ and not for the trivial reason that $0 \in S$, but it also has the property that $0 \in S+S+S+S$. But I'm a little lost on what you're asking. Are you asking whether some sequence always sums to $0$, or if it always happens without repeating summands, or if there's an algorithm? Does it matter to your question how long the sequence is?

Comment: I indeed assume $S$ is a finite set (actually a subset of the integers) and the question is if there is a subset of $S$ whose sum is zero (so indeed without repeating summands). To show there is a *sequence* (so with possibly repeating summands) is easy: start with any $s_0 \in S$, write $s_0=s_1+t_1,s_1=s_2+t_2$ and so on. Because of the finiteness of $S$, for some $i<j$ we have $s_i=s_j$ and wlog $i=0$ and then $t_1+\cdots +t_j=0$.